# How to reset the SIM7600 programmatically?

Tags: arduino, reset

I am using SIM7600 (Maduino Zero) in IOT to [post data](https://how2electronics.com/http-post-with-sim7600-arduino-send-data-to-server/) from a remote appliance.

Sometimes it loses connection to the wireless signal, and the only way to get it back is a reboot.

I tried to do `AT+CRESET` but that is not drastic enough.  I need to actually power cycle in order to fix it, but I can't physically do that.

I tried both of [these approaches](https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2015/11/reset-arduino-programmatically.html):
I tried to call a function at address 0, and I tried adding a jumper from a data pin to the RST pin and then OUTPUT LOW to the data pin.  In both cases, the SIM7600 freezes up and becomes useless until I do a physical power cycle.

Is there something else I can try?  Any suggestions welcome.

Here is [the board description](https://wiki.makerfabs.com/Maduino_Zero_4G_LTE.html), and schematics at the bottom of the page.

Comment: it is difficult to help you when we do not know what device you have ... please post a schematic diagram of the board

Comment: it has two reset buttons.  One for MCU which is the zero chip i suppose, and another for the SIM7600 reset.

Comment: do either of the reset buttons restore functionality after the device freezes?

Comment: Sometimes the SIM7600 reset button works.  And in that case "AT+CRESET" also works. However not always.  I think my best option is to use an ATTiny that is connected via I2C and if the ATTiny detects that the SIM7600 is stuck, it will power-cycle using a load switch.  But I don't know.  I've never done something like this before..